# 2019 FBAR filing deadline missed

Tags: united-states, irs, fbar

This year, I missed FBAR filing deadline of April 25 and also for automatic extension of October 15. It is not because of natural disaster (that's the only relief option I see here on [the IRS site](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/report-of-foreign-bank-and-financial-accounts-fbar).

I have been filing FBAR every year since the time I arrived in US (more than 5 years now).

What are my options?

I searched this site and Googled around but did not get a satisfactory answer as to how I should approach this.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your link there, there is a phone number next to "IRS FBAR Hotline". That seems like the logical next step, as I am pretty sure that they won't just let it go. There are probably penalties that you have to pay for missing deadlines, but the longer you delay, the worse those will get. I'd call them ASAP.